# Android RxJava можно ли вернуть из .subscribe() еще один Observable<>

Tags: android, rxjava, rxjava2

Используем (Android приложение):

```
implementation group: 'io.reactivex.rxjava2', name: 'rxjava', version: '2.1.16'
implementation group: 'io.reactivex.rxjava2', name: 'rxandroid', version: '2.0.2'
```

Подписываемся в классе презентера:

```
instanceClassExample.myMethod(myStr).subscribe(res -> {
             // Не делаем никаких проверок связанных с ответом сервера
             // делаем нужные действия с Activity
         }, err -> {
             // Не делаем никаких проверок связанных с ответом сервера
             // делаем нужные действия с Activity
         });
```

Метод `myMethod(String myStr)` класса `InstanceClassExample`:

```
public Observable<String> myMethod(String myStr) {
   // Делаем GET HTTP запрос на сервер
   appService.sendHttpRequest(myStr)
      .subscribe(res -> {
         // Делаем нужные проверки тут, 
         // что бы не выносить их в Main класс
         ?? Вернуть положительный результат
         ?? Или отрицательный, если не прошли проверки
      }, err -> {
         ?? Вернуть отрицательный результат
      });
}
```

`myMethod` возвращает `Observable<Response<String>>` (`import retrofit2.Response;`)

Т.е. я хочу вынести из презентеров логику проверки ответа сервера.

Comment: Вам нужны `map` и `onErrorResumeNext`. В них сделайте нужные проверки и верните из первого `true`, а из второго - `Observable.just(false)`

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Спасибо за ответ. Проблема в том, что для меня rxjava темный лес. Я с большим трудом понимаю что происходит внутри. Что есть в моем распоряжении. Как это использовать, и использовать правильно. Я читаю и перечитываю кучу статей про rxjava и более менее становится понятно после 2-5 прочтения. Как раз про map я и вычитал там и у меня получилось. А вот вместо onErrorResumeNext я пытался использовать doOnError, я так и не понял что он делает, но догадываюсь "что то, если возникнет ошибка".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам нужны операторы `map` и `onErrorResumeNext`. В них сделайте нужные проверки и верните из первого `true`, а из второго - `Observable.just(false)`

```
public Observable<String> myMethod(String myStr) {
   // Делаем GET HTTP запрос на сервер
   appService.sendHttpRequest(myStr)
      //в случае получения ответа делаем какие-то действия и меняем тип данных источника
      .map(response -> {
          //тут что-то делаем с ответом сервера
          //возвращаем значение другого типа:
          return true;
      })
      //В случае ошибки - меняем тип данных в источнике:
      . onErrorResumeNext(throwable -> Observable.just(false))
      .subscribe(res -> {
         //теперь сюда придёт true/false
      }, err -> {
         //по идее сюда мы не попадём
      });
}
```

Comment: Ещё раз спасибо, твой ответ помог сильно продвинуться вперёд. В err мне нужно попадать, если возникнет какая либо ошибка у android клиента (нет интернета например / или если я допущу ошибку в retrofit например) а в res должен попадать положительный ответ либо ошибка от сервера (неверный запрос клиента / внутренняя ошибка сервера). Внутреннюю ошибку сервера я тоже хочу прокинуть в err. Как буду возле компьютера, буду пробовать дальше. Мне кажется за пару часов я все сделаю.